# slideDown Doesn't work for me

Tags: jquery, html, css, slidedown

Why doesn't this jQuery code work?

```
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('currentPage').click(function() {
          $('myaccount').slideDown('slow', function() {
            // Animation complete.
          });
        });
    });

<li><a class="currentPage">Home</a></li>
<li><a class="myaccount">My Account</a></li>
```

Anyone got any ideas? I don't.

Comment: Given that you've posted comments to the effect that *both* answers fail to work, it might be worth posting your (x)html mark-up. Since both answers *should* work, unless there's something else going on.

Comment: Yeah, I would've posted the CSS that the classes refer to, but at the time of posting, it didn't occur to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We use dots to [select classes](http://api.jquery.com/class-selector/): `$('.class_name')`

```
    $('.currentPage').click(function() {
      $('.myaccount').slideDown('slow', function() {
        // Animation complete.
      });
    });
```

In your version, it's looking for `<currentPage>` tag.

**edit**
[An example](http://jsfiddle.net/mXh2C/).
It might seem 'not working' because myaccount link is already visible, so sliding it down won't change a thing. Thus, I've hidden it in the example above.

Comment: Thank you. I added dots, but it still doesn't work. It now looks like: *$('.currentPage')*   and   *$('.myaccount')*

Comment: @Lucifer I've added an example.

Comment: yay! Thank you @Nikita, much appreciated. jQuery is great.. It *looks* so simple, but at the same time there's something about it that really confuses my brain :P

Comment: Hi Nikita, I was also having trouble with this having set visibility: hidden in the css. I noted that you used display: none. When I set mine to display: none it worked also. ? Is this a requirement when using slideDown.

Answer (score 1):

You're missing a . on your class selectors:

`$('currentPage')` should be `$('.currentPage')`

and

`$('myaccount')` should be  `$('.myaccount')`

Comment: Thank you. I added dots, but it still doesn't work. It now looks like: $('.currentPage') and $('.myaccount')